# How to format API JSON output?

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, tkinter

I've started to look into using APIs in a python program with Tkinter recently, have so far been able to write a program that pulls travel data using TransportAPI in a travel planner across London tube stations.

The program so far works all fine, the only issue i'm having is formatting the returned JSON data into a readable format for the user. Below is the code for the function that creates the URL and displays the output in the program, and the current output when the program runs.

Creating API URL and returning output:

```
def create_url(): # creates API url using inputted / chosen values

    input_time = get_time()
    input_date = get_date()

    station_from = get_source()
    station_to = get_destination()

    search_url = 'https://transportapi.com/v3/uk/public/journey/from/'+station_from+'/to/'+station_to+'/at/'+input_date+'/'+input_time+'.json?app_id=bab9c3cc&app_key=0caef97a7e642a7d15f6f59efac6332c&modes=train&not_modes=bus-boat&service=tfl'

    return search_url
```

Displaying the output in the program window:

```
def display_results(): # displays API result to the user
    data = get_data()
    label_search_result.config(text=data)
```

Current output in the program:

```
{"request_time":"2019-06-10T00:50:45+01:00","source":"TfL journey planning
API","acknowledgements":"Transport for London","routes":
[{"duration":"00:09:00","route_parts":
[{"mode":"tube","from_point_name":"Stratford","to_point_name":"Liverpool
Street","destination":"Ealing
Broadway","line_name":"Central","duration":"00:09:00","departure_time":"12:46"
,"arrival_time":"12:55","coordinates":[[-0.00336,51.54171],[-0.00427,51.54114],[-0.00474,51.54078],[-0.00561,51.54003],[-0.00758,51.53835],[-0.00955,51.53671],[-0.01158,51.53537],[-0.01786,51.53208],[-0.01984,51.53117],[-0.02096,51.53064],[-0.0214,51.53037],[-0.0253,51.52724],[-0.02583,51.52699],[-0.02626,51.52688],[-0.02806,51.52654],[-0.03209,51.52567],[-0.03299,51.52548],[-0.03354,51.52533],[-0.03354,51.52533],[-0.03509,51.52494],[-0.03592,51.5247],[-0.0374,51.52418],[-0.03905,51.52366],[-0.04055,51.52328],[-0.04125,51.52314],[-0.04253,51.52314],[-0.04328,51.52324],[-0.04472,51.5236],[-0.0457,51.52393],[-0.04659,51.52435],[-0.04945,51.52616],[-0.04996,51.52643],[-0.05064,51.52665],[-0.0516,51.52684],[-0.05459,51.52706],[-0.05459,51.52706],[-0.0568,51.52722],[-0.05741,51.52722],[-0.062,51.52673],[-0.06601,51.52627],[-0.06796,51.526],[-0.06924,51.52575],[-0.07011,51.52552],[-0.07173,51.5248],[-0.07397,51.52386],[-0.0751,51.52336],[-0.0762,51.52271],[-0.08219,51.51805]]}],"departure_time":"12:46","departure_date":"2019-07-07","arrival_time":"12:55","arrival_date":"2019-07-07"},{"duration":"00:09:00","route_parts":[{"mode":"tube","from_point_name":"Stratford","to_point_name":"Liverpool Street","destination":"West Ruislip","line_name":"Central","duration":"00:09:00","departure_time":"12:48","arrival_time":"12:57","coordinates":[[-0.00336,51.54171],[-0.00427,51.54114],[-0.00474,51.54078],[-0.00561,51.54003],[-0.00758,51.53835],[-0.00955,51.53671],[-0.01158,51.53537],[-0.01786,51.53208],[-0.01984,51.53117],[-0.02096,51.53064],[-0.0214,51.53037],[-0.0253,51.52724],[-0.02583,51.52699],[-0.02626,51.52688],[-0.02806,51.52654],[-0.03209,51.52567],[-0.03299,51.52548],[-0.03354,51.52533],[-0.03354,51.52533],[-0.03509,51.52494],[-0.03592,51.5247],[-0.0374,51.52418],[-0.03905,51.52366],[-0.04055,51.52328],[-0.04125,51.52314],[-0.04253,51.52314],[-0.04328,51.52324],[-0.04472,51.5236],[-0.0457,51.52393],[-0.04659,51.52435],[-0.04945,51.52616],[-0.04996,51.52643],[-0.05064,51.52665],[-0.0516,51.52684],[-0.05459,51.52706],[-0.05459,51.52706],[-0.0568,51.52722],[-0.05741,51.52722],[-0.062,51.52673],[-0.06601,51.52627],[-0.06796,51.526],[-0.06924,51.52575],[-0.07011,51.52552],[-0.07173,51.5248],[-0.07397,51.52386],[-0.0751,51.52336],[-0.0762,51.52271],[-0.08219,51.51805]]}],"departure_time":"12:48","departure_date":"2019-07-07","arrival_time":"12:57","arrival_date":"2019-07-07"}]}
```

How would I go about formatting this data into something that is more readable by the user? For an idea, the ideal output would be something like this:

```
Source: Stratford
Destination: London Liverpool Street
Route:
Line: Central
To: Ealing Broadway
Duration: 09:00
Departure Time: 12:46
Arrival Time: 12:55

Source: Stratford
Destination: London Liverpool Street
Route:
Line: Central
To: West Ruslip
Duration: 09:00
Departure Time: 12:48
Arrival Time: 12:57
```

Comment: Json is parsed as a dictionary in python. Assuming the keys do not change, you could just parse the keys into your desired format

Answer (score 1):

Here is what the raw JSON data looks like formatted so it's a little more readable and you can see the structure it has more clearly — which is often helpful when doing this sort of thing:

```
{"acknowledgements": "Transport for London",
 "request_time": "2019-06-10T00:50:45+01:00",
 "routes": [{"arrival_date": "2019-07-07",
             "arrival_time": "12:55",
             "departure_date": "2019-07-07",
             "departure_time": "12:46",
             "duration": "00:09:00",
             "route_parts": [{"arrival_time": "12:55",
                              "coordinates": [[-0.00336, 51.54171],
                                               .
                                               .
                                               .
                                              [-0.08219, 51.51805]],
                              "departure_time": "12:46",
                              "destination": "Ealing Broadway",
                              "duration": "00:09:00",
                              "from_point_name": "Stratford",
                              "line_name": "Central",
                              "mode": "tube",
                              "to_point_name": "Liverpool Street"}]},
            {"arrival_date": "2019-07-07",
             "arrival_time": "12:57",
             "departure_date": "2019-07-07",
             "departure_time": "12:48",
             "duration": "00:09:00",
             "route_parts": [{"arrival_time": "12:57",
                              "coordinates": [[-0.00336, 51.54171],
                                               .
                                               .
                                               .
                                              [-0.08219, 51.51805]],
                              "departure_time": "12:48",
                              "destination": "West Ruislip",
                              "duration": "00:09:00",
                              "from_point_name": "Stratford",
                              "line_name": "Central",
                              "mode": "tube",
                              "to_point_name": "Liverpool Street"}]}],
 "source": "TfL journey planning API"}
```

You can convert that string from the API into a Python dictionary by using [`json.loads()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads), and afterwards, just iteration over its contents and put the keys and values into the format you want:

```
import json

data = json.loads(get_data())

for route in data['routes']:
    for route_part in route['route_parts']:
        print('Source:', route_part['from_point_name'])
        print('Route:')
        print('Line:', route_part['line_name'])
        print('To:', route_part['destination'])
        print('Duration:', route_part['duration'])
        # etc ...

        print()  # Blank line.
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to do is to parse the JSON string into a `dict` using the JSON module:

```py
import json

data = json.loads(get_data())
```

From now on, you can fetch data like with any dict, and use it to format a string. For example :

```py
pretty_data = ""
for route in data["routes"]:
    pretty_data += """Source: {}
Destination: {}

...""".format(route["route_parts"][0]["from_point_name"], route["route_parts"][-1]["to_point_name"])
```

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this helps, "data" should be a dictionary parsed from your JSON.

```
data = json_dictionary


print ('Request Time: ' + data['request_time'])
print ('Source: ' + data['source'])
print ('Acknowledgements: ' + data['acknowledgements'])
print ()


for x in (data['routes']):

    for y in x['route_parts']:

        print ('Departure Date: ' + x['departure_date'])
        print ('From Point Name: ' + y['from_point_name'])
        print ('To Point Name: ' + y['to_point_name'])
        print ('Destination: ' + y['destination'])
        print ('Line Name: ' + y['line_name'])
        print ('Duration: ' + y['duration'])
        print ('Departure Time: ' + y['departure_time'])
        print ('Duration: ' + y['duration'])
        print ('Arrival Time: ' + y['arrival_time'])

        #for z in y['coordinates']:
        #    print ('Coordinates' + z)

        print ()
```

**Output:**

```
Request Time: 2019-06-10T00:50:45+01:00
Source: TfL journey planning API
AcknowledgementsTransport for London

Departure Date: 2019-07-07
From Point Name: Stratford
To Point Name: Liverpool Street
Destination: Ealing Broadway
Line Name: Central
Duration: 00:09:00
Departure Time: 12:46
Duration: 00:09:00
Arrival Time: 12:55

Departure Date: 2019-07-07
From Point Name: Stratford
To Point Name: Liverpool Street
Destination: West Ruislip
Line Name: Central
Duration: 00:09:00
Departure Time: 12:48
Duration: 00:09:00
Arrival Time: 12:57
```